# Elliptical orbit, work done by gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, vectors, integration

Consider two points (A & B) on one half of an elliptical orbit.  Satellite moves from point A to B.  I want to calculate the work done by the gravitational force, but I DO NOT WANT to use energy conservation. I want to use

$W=$ Integral (from Ra to Rb) of $F dR .$

This should be a dot product and so, I should be able to write it as F Cos(angle) dR.  I can get the "right" answer if I just make angle = 0.  But it is obvious that the angle is not zero there is an angle between F (gravitational force, directed from the satellite to the central body) and dR (the delta of the two directional vectors, which should be tangential to the orbit, at some points this angle would be 90 degrees at others it would be much more than that.  Now I know that to integrate this the path shouldn't matter, but I want to do it that way, but all the books that I've look at just assume that F and dR have the same direction.  But that is clearly not true.  Again, I'm not interested in the answer, I know how to do it in several other ways, my question is why does FdR and not F Cosine (angle) dR works?

I hope I made it clear.

Answer (score 6):

Gravity is a radial force and is therefore always parallel to any change in the radial coordinate.

Possibly you are confusing a position vector with a radial coordinate?

i.e. $\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{l} = F\ dr$, where in polar coordinates, $d\vec{l} = dr\ \hat{r} + r d\phi\ \hat{\phi}$.

Comment: Can you pls explain what's the last term you wrote in the expression for $dl$

Comment: @PinkAura simplified it for orbital motion in a plane (which is all that is required here).

Comment: When you write F.dl, dl is the displacement vector, right?  On an elliptical orbit the direction of dl is tangential to the ellipse so NOT in the same direction as F (which goes straight from the satellite to the planet).  Therefore there is an angle between dl and F, they are NOT parallel, so you cannot write Fdr, it should be F dr Cosine (angle) where angle is whatever angle between that tangent and the direction of the gravitational force...where am I wrong?

Comment: @TonyDuarte It would be $F\ dl cos\theta$. The symbol $dr$ is a step in the radial direction.

Comment: Well, exactly, that is my point, but if you check most physics books, the will just tell you that you integrate F dr = integral (GM1M2/r^2, dr) with no "cos ()", now I know the answer won't change as the path taken will not change the result of the integral, but it is still wrong to say it is just Fdr, because F and dr do not have the same direction.  Am I correct?

Comment: @TonyDuarte It depends what you mean by $dr$. Most people use $r$ to indicate a radial coordinate. In which case, **it is** $F\ dr$. If you want to use $\vec{r}$ as a position vector, then it is $\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$, where $d\vec{r}$ is the thing I have called $d\vec{l}$ in my answer, precisely to avoid confusion. The line integral of a radial force **is** $F\ dr$.